# Truncate string to maximum length before space or dot to avoid breaking a word

Tags: php, ellipsis, maxlength, truncation, word-boundary

I found the following PHP script create by webbiedave.

```
// strip tags to avoid breaking any html
$string = strip_tags($string);
if (strlen($string) > 500) {
    // truncate string
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 500);

    // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
    $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="/this/story">Read More</a>';
}
echo $string;
```

Now my question is: How can I specify in `strrpos()` to search for space or dot?

So if I set a maximum string length of 22 and my inout string is:

```
StackOverFlow is the best site ever
```

Excluding the appended HTML tag, the output will be:

```
StackOverFlow is the...
```

If I have an input of:

```
http://stackoverflow.com is the best site ever
```

Excluding the appended HTML tag, the output will unfortunately be

```
...
```

How can I modify this script to cut text if it finds a dot in the string so that `http://stackoverflow.com is the best site ever` becomes `http://stackoverflow ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check string from end, cause You need to delete words that are incomplete. Condition of that incomplete word is when short string is not ending with space or with a end character such as '!' or just dot. Next cond is to see if +1 sign after end of string is also such character. If it is the You just have to del any character from end to next space. This could be done by regexp (something similiar to /[:alfa]+$/, probadly better would have to be done).

This is a simple way to do basic things, but a good start I think.

EXAMPLE of what it could be:

```
function word_wrap_custom($string, $limit){
$oneWord = explode(' ', $string);
if(count($oneWord) < 2 )
    return $oneWord[0];
$string = substr($string, 0, $limit + 2);

$endchar =  substr($string, $limit, $limit + 1);

$postendchar = substr($string, $limit + 1, $limit + 2);

$arrAccetpEndChar = array(' ', '!', '?', ',', '.', ';', ':');

if(in_array($postendchar, $arrAccetpEndChar) || in_array($endchar, $arrAccetpEndChar))
{
    return $string;
}
else
{
    return preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', '', $string);
}
}
```

Comment: It's work but your code have a bug.If I don't have space it will output only ...read more 
If I had something like 
    echo word_wrap_custom("Stackoverflow", "22");?> will output only ...read more if I put return preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', ' ...read more', $string);How can we fix this?

Comment: In a more accurate expression If I had one word will output me only ...read more.

Comment: Edited code above. Added a $oneWord var that will determine if there is a one word and if there is it will output only that word. Still it will output a string that is longer that limit. If you want to limit that word just replace "return $oneWord[0]" with "return substr($oneWord[0], 0, $limit)"

Comment: Thank you! I also added 
if(count($oneWord) > 1 AND strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;Because if I was have Chuck Norris he(the code) return Chuck ... even if strlen($string) was < $limit.So I fix that too.Thank you very much.

Comment: Some simple test cases: https://3v4l.org/s4RvZ

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to split this without breaking words, but while respecting line-limitations, use [`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) instead of any other split method.

```
$longText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut purus a tellus ultrices vulputate. Aliquam posuere facilisis elit ut adipiscing. Nunc auctor dignissim porta. Vestibulum vitae tempor augue. Nam vel odio quis quam gravida ultrices sed a arcu. Phasellus nec odio massa. Duis imperdiet rutrum mi, vitae volutpat nulla convallis quis. Donec dignissim pulvinar mauris id molestie. Duis id mauris augue, id sagittis velit. Ut justo lectus, scelerisque egestas tempor et, facilisis vitae erat. Quisque ut mattis nulla. Donec a justo quis nisi tempus ultrices. Phasellus non dui non dolor tristique tincidunt vitae imperdiet libero. Pellentesque pretium luctus sem.";

$makeLine = wordwrap( $longText, 50, PHP_EOL );

echo $makeLine;
```

Before and After: http://codepad.org/Dqz8qzAy

If you only wanted the first line, perhaps as a summary text, you could explode the resulting string and shift the first result off of the resulting array:

```
$longText = "...";

$makeLine = wordwrap( $longText, 50, '\r\n' );
$firstSen = array_shift( explode( '\r\n', $makeLine ) );

echo $firstSen; // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
```

Comment: Some test cases: https://3v4l.org/VPtJZ

Answer (score 0):

This on will not break words:

```
function ShortenText($text, $chars)
{
    $chars = $chars;$text = $text." ";
    $countchars = strlen($text);
    if($countchars > $chars)
    {
        $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
        $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
        $text = $text."...";
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Your code does the same as the one posted by me.So if I had 
    <?php echo ShortenText("StackOverFlow is the best site ever ", "22");?> will output StackOverFlow is the... and if I had
     <?php echo ShortenText("http://stackoverflow.com is the best site ever ", "22");?> will output only ... because he doesn't find space in first 22 characters. So that I want to search for dot OR space.

Comment: This answer does not prove to be satisfactory. https://3v4l.org/VPl1V