# How to show limited words in php

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [split a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137819/split-a-string-php)

I am newbie in PHP.i have a string like:

```
$string="Once the Flash message has been set, I redirect the user to the form or a list of results. That is needed in order to get the flash working (you cannot just load the view in this case… well, you can but this method will not work in such case). When comparing $result TRUE or FALSE, please notice the different value for type. I am using type=message for successful messages, and type=error for error mesages.";
```

Now i want to show the limited words like 15 or 20 only.than how can i do it?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want it to output the first 15-20 words of the whole string?

Comment: yes i want to show first 15 words of string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137819/split-a-string-php search before you ask!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

$content = 'Once the Flash message has been set, I redirect the user to the form or a list of results. That is needed in order to get the flash working (you cannot just load the view in this case… well, you can but this method will not work in such case). When comparing $result TRUE or FALSE, please notice the different value for type. I am using type=message for successful messages, and type=error for error mesages.' ; 

echo limit_words($content,20);
```

Answer (score 4):

This way you split the string in words, then you extract the desired amount:

```
function trimWords($string, $limit = 15)
{

    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$string = "Once the Flash message ...";
$words  = array_slice(explode(' ', $string), 0, 15);
$output = implode(' ', $words);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function time ago for this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @param string $str Original string
     * @param int $length Max length
     * @param string $append String that will be appended if the original string exceeds $length
     * @return string 
     */
    function str_truncate_words($str, $length, $append = '') {
        $str2 = preg_replace('/\\s\\s+/', ' ', $str); //remove extra whitespace
        $words = explode(' ', $str2);
        if (($length > 0) && (count($words) > $length)) {
            return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $length)) . $append;
        }else
            return $str;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sorry I misclicked on suggestion prompt - wouldn't `trim()` just do the work instead of the regex?

Comment: trim only clears whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string. with this regexp I wanted to remove double or more spaces, because if you don't do so, when exploding you'll have empty strings what will count as words.